# Counting in a while loop

Tags: linux, bash

I'm running a find on a directory to do certain operations on files. I also want to count how many files were affected, but some strange things have happened in the loop:

```
COUNTER=0

find . -type f -name "*.txt" | while read f
do 
  let COUNTER++
  echo Counter is $COUNTER # This shows COUNTER working...
done

echo Counter is $COUNTER # COUNTER is back to 0 at this point...
```

Why is `$COUNTER` resetting itself?

Comment: FAQ from [Bash Pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#grep_foo_bar_.7C_while_read_-r.3B_do_.28.28count.2B-.2B-.29.29.3B_done) also [I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)

Comment: @nwinkler While your proposed duplicate got more votes, that question also contains a distracting logic error. There are bound to be dozens of other duplicates to choose from, and mine may not be the best, either.

Comment: @tripleee Fair enough, I noticed that the same question had been asked and answered several times, and I picked the one with the most votes :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to:

```
COUNTER=0

while read -r entry
do 
  let COUNTER++
  echo Counter is $COUNTER # This shows COUNTER working...
done < <(find . -type f -name "*.txt")
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside the loop a new SubShell is created, and it has a different context, than the outside world. The already mentioned [page](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) summarizes this quite well. The other answer by @arco444 shows the *process substitution* workaround from this page.

A quote from the page which is relevant to the comments:

> BourneShell creates a subshell when the input or output of anything (loops, case etc..) but a simple command is redirected, either by using a pipeline or by a redirection operator ('<', '>').

So the problem is not the loop, but the use of the pipeline (`|`) operator.

Comment: do you know the reason why `bash` uses SubShell for `while` loop  ?

Comment: I don't exactly know, the page only says *In most shells, each command of a pipeline is executed in a separate SubShell.*. My guess is, that this comes down to the UNIX way of things: a shell is basically interoperating sot of separate programs.

Answer (score -1):

This also works:

```
COUNTER=0

for line in $(find . -type f -name "*.txt");
do
  let COUNTER++
  echo Counter is $COUNTER
done
```

Comment: $COUNTER is 0 outside of the loop, unfortunately

Comment: Probably it is shell dependent, because in my case $COUNTER outside loop is not 0. I use `GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`